# Automapper with Builder design pattern

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, builder

I have a bunch of classes that are instantiated using the Builder design pattern. For example, I might have a Car that uses the Builder design pattern that I instantiate like this:

```
Builder carBuilder = Car.CreateBuilder();
carBuilder.setColor("red");
carBuilder.setHorsepower(300);
Car car = carBuilder.Build();
car.color == "red"; // True
car.horsepower == 300; // True
```

How could I use Automapper to map from a standard class to this class? For instance, if I have a Truck that looks like this:

```
class Truck {
    public string color;
    public int horsepower;
}

Truck truck = new Truck();
truck.color = "blue";
truck.horsepower = 250;
```

How could I configure Automapper so that it can map a Truck into a Car?

```
Car newCar = Mapper.Map<Truck, Car>(truck); // This is how I want to use Automapper
car.color == "blue"; // Should be true
car.horsepower == 250; // Should be true
```

Comment: I posted this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60337756/1016183) where I use AutoMapper with the Builder design pattern

Answer (score 0):

You need setters for those properties. But the setters can be private. ConstructUsing would allow you to create a new object anyway you want.

Comment: I'm assuming you're talking about the properties on Car, correct? How would I get AutoMapper to call CreateBuilder() and Build()?

Comment: You don't, you just map into the object you create.

Comment: You can also use ConstructUsing to create the car from the truck.

Comment: I can't change the fact that I need to call CreateBuilder() and Build() to get an object, unfortunately. So I guess I should look at ConstructUsing. Is there an example or documentation for ConstructUsing anywhere? I Googled it and only got other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=constructusing).